# How to exclude rows where two fileds are empty or null?

Tags: python, pandas

How to exclude rows where two filed are empty or null in Pandas?

I have a dataset:

```
A B C 
1 2 ""
2 3 Null
1 2 3
```

I want to filter and leave rows where `C` not empty or not `null`.

I have tried this:

```
df[df["C"] != "" | df["C"].notnull() & df["B"] != "" | df["B"].notnull()]
```

In real dataframe I have:

```
df[~df['ZIP'].isin(["","Null"])].dropna(subset=["ZIP"])
df[~df['ADDRESS'].isin(["","Null"])].dropna(subset=["ADDRESS"])

df[df['ZIP'] != "None"]
df[df['ADDRESS'] != "None"]

df[df['ZIP'] != "none"]
df[df['ADDRESS'] != "none"]
```

As result I got rows ZIP with `None` inside

Comment: Think about `df["C"] != "" | df["C"].notnull()` one more time

Comment: Could you provide `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: This is okay?

`df["C"] != "" | df["C"].notnull() & df["B"] != "" | df["B"].notnull()` ?

Comment: I got this error: `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `isin()` to contemplate all cases and then use `dropna()` in case there are proper NaNs. Kindly try:

```
df[~df['C'].isin(["","Null","None"])].dropna(subset=["C"])
```

Comment: it is works only for `C` column right? I I need the same for B, I do similar?

Comment: It gives me error:

`FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.dropna will be keyword-only.
  df[~df['C'].isin(["","Null"])].dropna("C")`

Comment: In this case I'm using it only for C because of what you stated in your question. However it can be applied to more than a single column, do you need that? I can edit my question.

Comment: A FutureWarning shouldn't be an error in the execution, however please use the edited answer with the `subset` parameter.

Comment: Does it work for `None`?

Comment: Yes it does. That's what the `dropna()` is for, it considers proper `Null` values such as `None`,`NaN`,`NaT`.

Comment: I dont know why but i in result df I have empty C and B

Comment: I got `None` in output dataframe,

Comment: Then it was a string and not an actual Null, please have a read here to understand how to work with null values https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html and check my edited answer.

Comment: Could you check my question I have added an example I have

Comment: I can not find how to skip strings `None`

Comment: My answer should suffice as I have just tested it and it filters the data properly.

Comment: I still get `None` in column ZIP

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that `None ` you are talking about has an extra space at the end. Is this intended?

Comment: My filter is: `filter5 = ~df['ADDRESS'].isin(["","Null", "None", "NONE", "none"]).dropna(subset=["ADDRESS"])  df_filtered = df[filter5]`

Comment: Lets remove spaces in `ADDRESS`, `ZIP`

Comment: Try: `filter5 = ~df['ADDRESS'].str.strip().isin(["","Null", "None", "NONE", "none"]).dropna(subset=["ADDRESS"])`

Comment: `TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset'`

Comment: On the line `filter4 = ~df['ZIP'].str.strip().isin(["","Null", "None", "NONE", "none"]).dropna(subset=["ZIP"])`

Comment: `.str.strip()` also does not help

Comment: ADDRESS      object  ZIP object  are object type

Comment: I have found colution: `df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['ADDRESS'].notna()]`